# how to display table data in newsletter plaintext

Tags: email, newsletter

Im working on a newsletter, wehre i have to display table data in plain text.
I was wondering if somebody has an good idea how to display it?

I tried it like this, but im not really happy with this solution!

```
-----------------------------------------
Table Title
-----------------------------------------
Head 1: Val 1
Head 2: Val 2
Head 3: Val 3
Head 4: Val 4
Head 5: Val 5

Head 1: ...
Head 2: ...
Head 3: ...
Head 4: ...
Head 5: ...
```

Comment: Maybe actually “draw” a table using unicode characters …? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use bars and dashes like so:

```
|  How  | about  |
| like  | this?  |
------------------
|  or   | with   |
------------------
| horiz | lines  |
```